# Bash format returns zeroes for H M

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, date

I'm trying to understand this behaviour of `date` in bash script. 
When I call date by itself and when I format the date I get different outputs.

```
date
Wed Aug 31 22:12:25 EDT 2016
date --date="$NOW" +"%X %x"
12:00:00 AM 08/31/2016
date --date="$NOW" +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
2016/08/31 00:00:00
```

As you can see the time portion is zeroed out. Why is formatted date result different than just calling `date` ?

Comment: Is `$NOW` empty? as noted under `DATE STRING` in the GNU date manual page, "An empty string indicates the beginning of the day."

Comment: Bingo! `$NOW` was empty, I've removed it as per @Sato Katsura suggestion and it works! Can you post as an answer for me to accept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$` that is referring to an obviously unset variable and you'll get what you want:

```
date --date="NOW" +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
```

The same logical representation can allow you to show the date for `tomorrow`, `next week`, `+1 week`, `last week`, `+1 day`, and much more.

Comment: Or just leave out `--date="NOW"` altogether?

Comment: Of course, but the point here is to show that it supports logical representation of the date.

Comment: Sorry the `$` was actually to show it's a shell entry (not a response). It is not there in my actual command. I'll try without the `--date="NOW"`. I'll also edit the misleading `$` out of my question :)